# How does the Sulley fuzzing framework procmon work on a virtual machine?

Tags: fuzzing, procmon

From my understanding, the process_monitor stores crashbin information locally. If this is running on a virtual machine and a test case causes the process and target machine to become unresponsive, vmcontrol would then revert to an earlier snapshot. How is the crashbin information displayed to the web interface, or accessed at this point if it was lost on the revert to an earlier snapshot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be beyond the scope of SO

Comment: Okay, thanks anyways!

Comment: @Strawberry Why does it seem off-topic? This seems to me to fall under the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JoshP I would suggest that a combined total of 88 questions and 20 followers rather proves my point - but mine is just one solitary vote

Comment: @Strawberry Do you mean to say that this tool is not common enough to qualify?

Answer (score 1):

After walking through most of the code in the Sulley environment, I found that the restart_target() method in the sessions.py module calls for a restart on the virtual machine if vmcontrol is available first, and then tries to restart the process via the procmon if its available. By switching the order of these, I can solve the problem of losing the log information from the crashbin unless the entire target machine becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Nice! Please consider making a pull request to the Github site, and also to my fork https://github.com/jtpereyda/sulley